# Rotate circle (SKSpriteNode) by finger and position of point on a circle

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to rotate circleWithArrow by finger and always to know position of point on this circle.
I tried different approaches and at the moment.
I think this is a pure mathematics ... 
I've got following code:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(location)

    if let name = touchedNode.name {
        if name == "circleWithArrow" {
            let dx = location.x - touchedNode.position.x
            let dy = location.y - touchedNode.position.y
            let angle = atan2(dy, dx)
            var deltaAngle = angle - startingAngle

            if abs(deltaAngle) > CGFloat(M_PI) {
                if (deltaAngle > 0) {
                    deltaAngle = deltaAngle - CGFloat(2*M_PI)
                } else {
                    deltaAngle = deltaAngle + CGFloat(2*M_PI)
                }
            }

            let dt = CGFloat(touch.timestamp - startingTime)
            let actionRotate = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: deltaAngle, duration: TimeInterval(dt))
            touchedNode.run(actionRotate)

            // Update angle and time
            startingAngle = angle
            startingTime = touch.timestamp

            if let spot = self.childNode(withName: "spot") as? SKSpriteNode {
            let factor = 308 / 2 * sin(angle) //circleWithArrow.size.width == 308
            spot.position.x = (self.defaultSpotPosition?.x)! + factor

            print("zPosition: \(touchedNode.zPosition)") //always: zPosition: 0.0
        }     
    }
}}
```

I would like to link the position.x of the end of my arrow with a posiion.x of a spot.
I don't understand how to synchronise them.
The end of the arrow on circle is only a point on the SKSpriteNode.
I'd like to rotate "circleWithArrow" and  use it as a controller of a spot position.
I think if I could knew zPosition of "circleWithArrow" I could calculate x of the end of arrow (point on the circle) but I found SKAction.rotate doesn't have impact on zPosition of the node.

[image: It should look like that]

Comment: Huh, why are you looking at zPosition? You do realize that is depth (or height as Apple calls it)? `rotate` rotates around the z-axis, so only the x and y values would be changed.

Comment: touchedNode.position.x & touchedNode.position.y in this case are always the same. I am looking for solution to link top middle point of circle with arrow & spot's position. I need a method to obtain position of point on circle during & after rotation

Comment: Could anybody help me - maybe possible to add some listener on rotation in order to get information about position of point on the circle?